# How to create a new column in a data frame depending on multiple criteria from multiple columns from the same data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df1` with four variables. One refers to sunlight, the second one refers to the moon-phase light (light due to the moon's phase), the third one to the moon-position light (light from the moon depending on if it is in the sky or not) and the fourth refers to the clarity of the sky (opposite to cloudiness).

I call them `SL`, `MPhL`, `MPL` and `SC` respectively. I want to create a new column referred to "global light" that during the day depends only on `SL` and during the night depends on the other three columns ("MPhL", "MPL" and "SC"). What I want is that at night (when `SL == 0`), the light in a specific area is equal to the product of the columns "MPhL", "MPL" and "SC". If any of them is 0, then, the light at night would be 0 also.

Since I work with a matrix of hundreds of thousands of rows, what would be the best way to do it? As an example of what I have:

```
SL<- c(0.82,0.00,0.24,0.00,0.98,0.24,0.00,0.00)
MPhL<- c(0.95,0.85,0.65,0.35,0.15,0.00,0.87,0.74)
MPL<- c(0.00,0.50,0.10,0.89,0.33,0.58,0.00,0.46)
SC<- c(0.00,0.50,0.10,0.89,0.33,0.58,0.00,0.46)
df<-data.frame(SL,MPhL,MPL,SC)
df
    SL MPhL  MPL   SC
1 0.82 0.95 0.00 0.00
2 0.00 0.85 0.50 0.50
3 0.24 0.65 0.10 0.10
4 0.00 0.35 0.89 0.89
5 0.98 0.15 0.33 0.33
6 0.24 0.00 0.58 0.58
7 0.00 0.87 0.00 0.00
8 0.00 0.74 0.46 0.46
```

What I would like to get is this:

```
df
    SL MPhL  MPL   SC   GL
1 0.82 0.95 0.00 0.00 0.82 # When "SL">0, GL= SL
2 0.00 0.85 0.50 0.50 0.21 # When "SL" is 0, GL = MPhL*MPL*SC
3 0.24 0.65 0.10 0.10 0.24
4 0.00 0.35 0.89 0.89 0.28
5 0.98 0.15 0.33 0.33 0.98
6 0.24 0.00 0.58 0.58 0.24
7 0.00 0.87 0.00 0.00 0.00
8 0.00 0.74 0.46 0.46 0.16
```

Comment: Thanks for including sample data and your desired output. What have you tried so far and did you run into any errors (e.g., taking too long, not desired results, etc.)?

Comment: I didn't know how to manage this question. I started with this script: df[,5] <- lapply(df$SL, function(x) ifelse(x>0, x, "NA")). My idea was to apply another script after that when SL=0. But then I thought it should be better to ask here how to do it at once with one script.

Comment: No worries, this is a good place to ask. For the future, it is good practice to put your attempted solution along with your question. That way, people see that you tried and can address specific reasons why your answer did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most simple way would be to use the `ifelse` function:

```
GL <- ifelse(SL == 0, MPhL * MPL * SC, SL)
```

If you want to work in a more structured environment, I can recommend the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(SL = SL, MPhL = MPhL, MPL = MPL, SC = SC) %>% 
  mutate(GL = if_else(SL == 0, MPhL * MPL * SC, SL))
    # A tibble: 8 x 5
     SL  MPhL   MPL    SC       GL
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1  0.82  0.95  0.00  0.00 0.820000
2  0.00  0.85  0.50  0.50 0.212500
3  0.24  0.65  0.10  0.10 0.240000
4  0.00  0.35  0.89  0.89 0.277235
5  0.98  0.15  0.33  0.33 0.980000
6  0.24  0.00  0.58  0.58 0.240000
7  0.00  0.87  0.00  0.00 0.000000
8  0.00  0.74  0.46  0.46 0.156584
```